# Why is this code giving a "stray '\' in program" error?

Tags: c++, for-loop, pointers, compiler-errors, null

[image: Code]

I came across this question while practicing *pointer* questions, and, according to my understanding, I thought option C would be correct, but Option D was the correct answer, so I ran the code in Visual Studio Code and it did give a *compilation* error.

Strings are terminated by a NULL character. Then why is an error occurring if the *for* loop is checking for the occurrence of the NULL character?

[image: Error message]

What is the problem with this code? Here is the actual code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char st[] = "ABCD";
  for(int i = 0; st[i] != ‘\0’; i++) {
     cout << st[i] << *(st)+i << *(i+st) << i[st];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: It is the wrong close reason. It should be closed as a duplicate of the canonical question *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/)*.

Comment: Not all errors are shown here, but from what is: 342 200 231 (octal)   → 0xE2 0x80 0x98 (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+2019 ([RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8212&number=128)).

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Answer (score 4):

`‘` (U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) and `’` (U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) are Unicode characters, and your source file is saved in UTF-8.

You likely copied this code from some website which used these characters.

You need to use ASCII `'` (U+0027 APOSTROPHE) instead:

```
st[i] != '\0'
```

Comment: thanks after using ' problem was solved and code ran perfectly

Comment: They can be searched for (and replaced) by using the regular expression `\x{2018}|\x{2019}` in any modern text editor or IDE (note: The notation is different in Visual Studio Code (and probably others): `\u2018|\u2019` (instead of `\x{2018}|\x{2019}`)).